# Excel: retrieve all values from column 2 having the same column 1 value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in MS Excel. i want to retrieve a list of all corresponding values in a different column having the same first column value. For example, from a State's  monthly weather data table I need all mintemp and maxtemp of all days having the same location.

```
location     date      mintemp        maxtemp
A           7/1/14        61             84
A           7/2/14        65             89
A           7/3/14        70             75
B           7/1/14        32             40
B           7/2/14        29             42
```

Say I want only A's data. `VLOOKUP` function will extract only one value of `A` from this table. I could take a combination of location and date and use in `VLOOKUP` but that's a big deal.

Comment: Do you need it formulaically, or is this something you could solve using a pivot table?

Comment: I assume you want the MIN temp of location A, and the MAX temp of Location A.  Can you switch to MS Access. A simple Group By Location Query with MIN and MAX as fields.  Done.

Comment: Just apply a filter on the location column

Comment: Well, I see no other option than making a macro which applies filter on the location and then copy paste the desired columns. I was expecting a function will do the same. anywys tnx guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a table as below, with your location, date, mintemp & maxtemp in **columns A-D** (I added some more data, to better demonstrate)

Cell **F2** is the selection cell. Here you type the location identifier you are interested in. (results below for A and B)

to populate cells G2:I6(the **filtered results**) you have to do the following:

- define a range called `data` referring to `A2:D10` (let me know if u dont know how)
- define a range called `locations` referring to `A2:A10`
- select cells G2:I6, click the formula bar and type the following: `=OFFSET(data,MATCH(F2,locations,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(locations,F2),3)`
- accept the formula by pressing ctrl-shift-enter (this will create an array-formula and curly braces will appear around your formula)

  ```
  my Example Table:
          A           B           C       D           E   F           G           H       I
      -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |   location    date        mintemp maxtemp         location    date        mintemp maxtemp
  2   |   A           07/01/2014  66      84              A           07/01/2014  66      84
  3   |   A           07/02/2014  65      89                          07/02/2014  65      89
  4   |   A           07/03/2014  64      75                          07/03/2014  64      75
  5   |   A           08/03/2014  63      75                          08/03/2014  63      75
  6   |   A           09/03/2014  62      75                          09/03/2014  62      75
  7   |   B           07/01/2014  32      40                  
  8   |   B           07/02/2014  29      42                  
  9   |   C           07/01/2014  61      84                  
  10  |   C           07/02/2014  65      89                      

          A           B           C       D           E   F           G           H   I   
      -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |   location    date        mintemp maxtemp         location    date        mintemp maxtemp
  2   |   A           07/01/2014  66      84              B           07/01/2014  32      40
  3   |   A           07/02/2014  65      89                          07/02/2014  29      42
  4   |   A           07/03/2014  64      75                          #N/A        #N/A    #N/A
  5   |   A           08/03/2014  63      75                          #N/A        #N/A    #N/A
  6   |   A           09/03/2014  62      75                          #N/A        #N/A    #N/A
  7   |   B           07/01/2014  32      40                  
  8   |   B           07/02/2014  29      42                  
  9   |   C           07/01/2014  61      84                  
  10  |   C           07/02/2014  65      89
  ```